# Should I make separate "responding script" for different devices?

Tags: javascript, php, json, cross-platform

- **Responding script** will be that script which will respond to the **Showing script's** requests, this script can add, get, update, delete data and can manipulate things, but the result data will only 
  come out as JSON
      **like this:**

  `{"success":0,"error":"userName already exist!"}`
- **Showing scripts**  will be that scripts which will send requests to the **responding script** and get that JSON data and will use how it
  want.

  [image: request-><-data]
- one **responding script** (not for whole site, it is like one script
  for one thing) will work with all devices, but will make separate
  **showing script** for different devices.
- My main question is, should I make only one **responding script** or 
  separate for different devices? what will be more easy to handle? pros and cons of both?

  one pro of making separate
  **responding script** will be that    the load of traffic will be dived

*one thing I want to clear that my English is not very well*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading into the [MVC principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Your `showing scripts` are a combination of controllers and views. Your `responding scripts` could be a combination of controllers and models. Try to make a distinction between the 3 of them!

That in mind, your 'showing script' (view) can be device depended, but try to reuse as much code as you can (avoid duplicate code).
Your 'responding script' should always receive input in the same format and should always sent out its response in the same fashion. This way, you could query the script via php, javascript, or whatever. The choice to use JSON as output-format is a good one for this in my opinion.

As for your last bullet; the load will not be divided as long as everything runs on 1 server. It's a server which is under load, not the script

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, really appreciated